# I have a post http request in rails in which I have to send URL params along with body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

The HTTP POST request is such that there are URL params and there is a body. Through postman, I am getting the response but when I am using Net::HTTP::Post, I am receiving no data.

The URL params include user and token. The body contains collection_name which is a hash.

How can I get the response using Net::HTTP::Post when I have URL params and body data.

Comment: You have to parse the data after success with inspect the result.

Comment: How do I parse the data

Comment: You need to first mentioned the result what you are getting and if possible share some code base as well.

Comment: Can you tell me how do I differentiate between URL params and body when I send a request using Net::HTTP::POST